# ansible via virtualenv gives ERROR: [Errno 21] Is a directory

Tags: python, ansible

I have an issue globally on my iMac ( M1 incase it matters )
where the commands exit with `import ansible` module is missing

So I tried installing a tmp dir with virtual env and tried using Ansible from there w/o luck.

I'll start from the error:

```
$ ../venv/bin/ansible-inventory
ERROR: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/private/tmp/testansible/z'
```

File structure is like this:

```
~/$ cd /tmp
tmp$ mkdir testansible && cd $_
testansible$ mkdir z
testansible$ virtualenv venv
testansible$ venv/bin/pip3 install ansible
```

Then in a different directory i'm trying to use it:

```
testansible$ cd z
z$ ../venv/bin/ansible-config init > ansible.cfg
```

Then running any ansible command gave me tons of errors:

```
ERROR: Invalid settings supplied for DEFAULT_GATHER_TIMEOUT
ERROR: Invalid settings supplied for DEFAULT_NULL_REPRESENTATION
ERROR: Invalid settings supplied for DEFAULT_REMOTE_PORT
ERROR: Invalid settings supplied for GALAXY_IGNORE_INVALID_SIGNATURE_STATUS_CODES
```

Which is strange by itself because their comments says that if there's no value - it will take some default from somewhere

Each one I "resolved" by commenting them out

Then the command worked:

```
z$ ../venv/bin/ansible-config init > ansible.cfg
```

But every other ansible command i'm trying to execute gives the same error:

```
z$ ../venv/bin/ansible -i inventory.hosts
ERROR: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/private/tmp/testansible/z'

z$ ../venv/bin/ansible-inventory -i inventory.hosts
ERROR: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/private/tmp/testansible/z'
```

Any ideas ?

#### Edit

Thanks to the comment below the issue was this line in the `ansible.cfg` file:

```
# (path) File to which Ansible will log on the controller. When empty logging is disabled.
log_path=
```

Commenting out this line - and the ansible commands started working.
I'm not sure , why across the file it says: `When empty logging is disabled` - but it's not disabled, it throws an exception. so as all the above variables, they don't really have a default value - they are just getting in the way

Comment: What happens if you run from a dir without any `ansible.cfg` on the way? You usually don't need that file, more spceifically when trying to debug this kind of problem. And the correct way to generate an example configuration file (i.e. with all options commented out by default) is `ansible-config init --disabled --type all > /path/to/ansible.cfg`

Comment: mmm you're right, w/o this file it works, i was tried to avoid the `-i <inventory_file>` so i'll try to debug it and see exactly what is causing this - thanks !

Comment: Well now you know it works without a bloated config file, you can create one with just what you need: `echo -e "[defaults]\ninventory=/path/to/inventory" > ansible.cfg`. Alternatively, you can create a full blown example file with the command in my first comment and enable only the lines you actually need.